# Find the limit for both

Tags: limits

Could someone please take me through the steps of solving these limits. I have tried so many different ways of simplifying but I am just not able to get how to solve these two.

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\sqrt{x+1}(1-\sqrt{2x+3})}{4x^2-6x+7}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4},$$

and

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x}\right)=2.$$

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: Hint to (1) : Divide by $x^2$. (both sides of fraction)

Comment: Hint to (2): First multiply and divide by $\sqrt{x^2+2x}+\sqrt{x^2-2x}$, then put the term $x^2$ in evidence in denomonator.

Comment: The second one, does it tend towards $-\infty$ or $\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1): there are various ways of approaching a limit, a common way for limits of the form $x \to \pm \infty$ is to divide by $x$ with the greatest exponent in both the numerator and the denominator (and thus multiplying by $1$). In this case: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{x+1}(1-\sqrt{2x+3})}{4x^2 -6x +7} *\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^2}} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{\sqrt{x^3 + x^2}-\sqrt{(x^3 +x^2)(2x+3)}}{x^2}}{\frac{4x^2-6x+7}{x^2}}$$ Splitting (knowing that $x^2 = \sqrt{x^4}$), we roughly get $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x^4}+\frac{x}{x^4}}-\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{x^4} + \cdots}}{\frac{4x^2}{x^2} + \cdots}$$ Aplying the limit we get $$-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

For (2): There's a trick called "multiplying by the conjugate", a conjugate of $\sqrt{\alpha}-\sqrt{\beta}$ is $\sqrt{\alpha} + \sqrt{\beta}$, we do this because $(\sqrt{\alpha}-\sqrt{\beta})(\sqrt{\alpha} + \sqrt{\beta}) = \alpha - \beta$. So: $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\sqrt{x^2+2x} - \sqrt{x^2-2x})*\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x} + \sqrt{x^2-2x}}{\sqrt{x^2+2x} + \sqrt{x^2-2x}}$$ $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2+2x -(x^2 - 2x)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x} + \sqrt{x^2-2x}}$$ Apply the same trick that we used in (1) and we're done.

**Remark:** This *tricks* are common on engineering courses, they aren't fully formal.

Comment: I just have to ask, xSgrt(x+1)=sqrt(x^3+x^2) where can I find the rules for this?

Comment: $x=x^1=x^{2*\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{x^2}$. And, also: $\sqrt{a*b}=\sqrt{a}*\sqrt{b}$. Perhaps this would help: http://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-1/exponents-and-exponential-functions/properties-of-exponents

Comment: What about x^3, then?

Comment: $x*\sqrt{x+1} = \sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x+1} = \cdots$

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Would you be able to point me into a direction where I can find rules and similar smart solutions?

Comment: But, should I say, you must be careful: if x tends towards a negative value, $x \neq \sqrt{x^2}$, but rather $x=-\sqrt{x^2}$. All of this is very informal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15645/discussion-between-miguelgondu-and-alexander).

Answer (score 1):

- For the first limit we have

$$x\sqrt{x+1}\left(1-\sqrt{2x+3}\right)\sim_\infty -x\sqrt x\sqrt{2x}=-\sqrt2 x^2$$
so
$$\frac{x\sqrt{x+1}\left(1-\sqrt{2x+3}\right)}{4x^2-6x+7}\sim_\infty-\sqrt2\frac{x^2}{4x^2}=-\frac{\sqrt2}{4}$$

- For the second limit we multiply by the conjugate  of the given expression and we repeat the method of the first point i.e. constants are neglected to $x$ at $\infty$.